# Calling a GI using workflow action

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to call a custom GI using workflow action in the customer screen. When I publish the customization package, it displays the button but while clicking it does not bring back any data.

[image]

How do I fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have defined the parameter in the GI:
[image]

And a condition filter using that parameter:
[image]

Your issue is likely that a GI is not a processing screen:
[image]

Try using a Navigation action type instead of workflow to navigate to the GI:
[image]

This is the expected result:
[image]

Comment: I don't think you can navigate to a GI using a workflow action type. If you must have navigation initiated by a button press I would recommend to use a custom action defined in graph extension instead of using the workflow customization.